# Why is the Facebook login dialog opening in Safari when building their framework for ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

When I'm building the Facebook framework for ARC on iOS, the login dialog is opening in Safari instead of a separate dialog.

What can I do to get this to open in a separate dialog, and not in Safari when building for ARC?

Comment: Please stop using boldface for your questions. I've edited this one to be much more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before compiling facebook api file open `facebook.m` file then go to the method `[facebook authorize:nil];` and set `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];` and then compile it.

Answer (score 0):

After making changes as described by Khoool i.e. `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]` in `Facebook.m` located in the src folder which is in facebook-ios-sdk a great reference for including the modified facebook-ios-sdk into your Xcode project and performing the compilation is: http://nabtech.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/facebook-ios-sdk-and-arc/

Note: Notepad++ can be used to make the change on line 336 of the `Facebook.m` file before adding to the Xcode project and compiling.

Before finding this stackoverflow solution I was using techniques that involved compiling `build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh`. Using this technique for ARC does not make the `Facebook.m` file visible so that the change `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]` can be made.